# MySQL Stored Procedure Requiring SUPER

Tags: mysql, permissions, stored-procedures

I'm trying to figure out a "safe" way of allowing a non-SUPER user to execute a specific command requiring SUPER privileges, i.e. `SET SESSION binlog_format = 'MIXED'`. I don't want to grant the user SUPER privileges for security reasons. Can this be accomplished using a stored procedure or any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have stored procedures execute as the definer instead of the invoker:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'admin'@'localhost' PROCEDURE p1()
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
  UPDATE t1 SET counter = counter + 1;
END;
```

See: [Access Control for Stored Programs and Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-security.html)

Comment: Definer context is actually the default in MySQL unless `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` is specified, but, yes, this is a common and viable approach.